# Google Analytics 4 property tracking React app now that Google is discontinuing Universal Analytics properties

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

So... every tutorial on using Google Analytics with React specifies to use Universal Analytics property only. However, Google says:

````
Universal Analytics properties will stop collecting data starting July 1, 2023. It’s recommended that you create a Google Analytics 4 property instead.```

So what's the solution for us React users??
````

Answer (score 0):

Why would React have influence on how you track things?

This mapping should guide you through how to map your existing tracking to GA4: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10270783?hl=en

The framework you use doesn't matter since tracking, in essence, is just JS.